# How can I add operator ternary on jQuery validate?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

My html code like this :

```
<form class="validatedForm" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="password" id="password" />
        <input name="password_confirmation" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
<button>Validate</button>
```

My JavaScript code to validate with jQuery validate like this :

```
jQuery('.validatedForm').validate({
    rules: {
        "password": {
            minlength: 6
        },
        "password_confirmation": {
            minlength: 6,
            equalTo : "#password"
        }
    },
      messages: {
            "password": 'Please enter a password, minimal 6 characters',
            "password_confirmation": 'Please confirm your password'
    },
});
```

Demo and full code like this : http://jsfiddle.net/oscar11/fEZFB/609/

I want to add condition in jQuery validate

If password filled, `required: true` on password_confirmation

If password not filled, `required: false` on password_confirmation

Seems I need to add operator ternary on rules password_confirmation. But I'm still confused

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

I try to make an answer for your problem, check this out

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.validatedForm').validate({
    rules: {
      "password": {
        minlength: 6,
      },
      "password_confirmation": {
        minlength: 6,
        required: function(element) {
          return $("input[name=password]").val() != "";
       },
        equalTo : "#password"
      }
    },
    messages: {
      "password": 'Please enter a password, minimal 6 characters',
      "password_confirmation": 'Please confirm your password'
    },
  });

  $('button').click(function () {
    console.log($('.validatedForm').valid());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js"></script>

<form class="validatedForm" id="commentForm" method="get" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <input name="password" id="password" />
        <input name="password_confirmation" />
    </fieldset>
</form>
<button>Validate</button>
```